# Not able to connect to VM from web browser with SAS University Edition

Tags: networking, virtualization, ports

I have installed SAS University Edition through Oracle Virtual Box as intended. The user is meant to connect to SAS from outside the VM via a web browser. Unfortunately, I am unable to make a connection. From my limited skills, it appears the given ports are not open. Interestingly I have tried on a Mac and Windows with the same result.

Below is the help page provided by SAS in order to give you a little more context as to what I am trying to achieve -

https://support.sas.com/software/products/university-edition/faq/trouble_error_cannot_connect.htm

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with VirtualBox, but I do recall having to set up a port-forwarder just so I could SSH to a guest linux vm on my windows system at work. I don't know the SAS thing at all. Is it a prebuilt VM/vApp? The port forwarding might be misconfigured, or you may lack the privileges on your host system to bind a port for forwarding.

Comment: I did read about having to setup a port-forwarder, but if that was the case I assume that there would be a large number of people experiencing the same issue as me. Plus there is no mention of this in the help guides. It is a prebuilt VM/vApp.

Comment: Found this, hope it helps. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10532299/3407600